# Can anyone work in HarmonyOS lib development?

Tags: android, huawei-mobile-services, huawei-developers, harmonyos, deveco-studio

I am a fresher who only knows only java. can I work on HarmonyOS lib development or else I should know the android development to work on HarmonyOS. Can anyone explain it, please?
Where I can learn?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's not about programming.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you could learn from the [official docs](https://developer.harmonyos.com/en/documentation/):

HarmonyOS provides multi-programming-language APIs for you to develop applications. You can choose from Java, Extensible Markup Language (XML), C/C++, JavaScript (JS), Cascading Style Sheets (CSS), and HarmonyOS Markup Language (HML).

The following shows the technical architecture of HarmonyOS.

[image]

[Setting Up a Windows Development Environment](https://device.harmonyos.com/en/docs/documentation/guide/quickstart-standard-windows-environment-0000001216019037)

Here are some [codelabs](https://developer.harmonyos.com/en/docs/documentation/doc-guides/codelabs-0000001141821381) and [samples](https://developer.harmonyos.com/en/docs/documentation/doc-guides/samples-0000001162414961), which may help you better understand the development for key features and scenarios.